# Can't clear / scroll-back buffer when using tail -f alacritty?

Tags: macos, tail, alacritty

When I use tail with the `-f` option, I can not find anyway to clear the screen. It just shows a `^L`. Same problem when following live logs with docker.

While I'm just in the shell, the `cmd-k` works fine.

I raised this issue on github (https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty), but they quickly dismissed this as not their problem.

Can anyone shine some light on whats going on? I would assume the screen clearing is part of the Terminal app. Apple's default `Terminal` and `iTerm` seem to have no problem with this.

Thanks!

Comment: clearing the screen with a single form-feed character is a nonstandard feature for terminal emulators (some shells do this, and some terminal developers got confused about their role in the process).   See [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_form_feed)

Comment: @ThomasDickey thanks. You say 'single form-feed char', any change you can do it any other way? Whatever the reason is, I hope you agree that this is unusable. I have 10ths of servers that all have std. tail installed. I see no way around that. On top the same for docker. Not be able to clean the screen is a _nighgtmare_

Comment: Some terminal emulators have a menu which provides a clear-screen feature.  Terminal.app has *Edit*, with *Clear Screen*.